# Solving circular import issues

Tags: compiler-construction, programming-languages, interpreter, language-design, abstract-syntax-tree

OK, so I'm currently writing an interpreter (for a language of my own design) and have an issue dealing with `import`s.

Here's how the interpreter works :

- Once an `import <somefile>;` statement is executed, `somefile` is loaded, parsed and executed.
- This means that if a function/class is declared in `somefile`, an entry has been created in our global function table, so that it can be called, from that point on.
- Then we move on to the next statement. And execute it.

Now here are the issues...

**Issue 1:**

- Let's say there is a `doSth` function in file `file1` and imported in `file2`
- If there's a `file3` importing `file2`, this means that `file1`'s actions are also available. Which is not desirable.

**Issue 2:**

- If `file1` imports `file2` (because, let's say we need to use a function in `file2`) and `file2` imports `file1`, this leads in a circular reference (which will most likely keep running till the end of time)

---

So, how could these be resolved? Any ideas?

I know the question is very specialized and complex, but if have any idea how this issue is handled by existing interpreters/compiler, please shed some light! ;-)

Comment: You need to look into topological sorting.

Comment: Looks like you have forgotten to design the module system of your language?

Comment: What's the language for? More could be said, but we're short on context.

Answer (score 2):

**Issue 1**

C and friends exhibit exactly the behaviour you complain of, demonstrating that however undesirable it may be, it is possible to live with :) However, many other languages have the same opinion you do. All of the solutions I know of are some variation of "declared exports". Generally, you need some mechanism to specify which definitions are exported (or which definitions are *not* exported); if you require an imported definition to be re-exported explicitly then you no longer suffer from default re-exports.

However, you now end up with a slightly different problem:

```
file3:
  export cool_definition

file2:
  import file3
  export bland_definition
  /* Use cool_definition */

file1:
  import file2 /* Note: only bland_definition is imported */
  import file3 /* We want cool_definition */
```

Now you probably have to make sure that `cool_definition` has the same meaning when used directly in `file1` as when it is used by `bland_definition` from `file2`. (Depending on how stateful your language is, and how much you care about eliminating code duplication, etc.)

**Issue 2**

Presuming that you agree that preprocessor import-guards are a ridiculous hack, then you need to remember which files have been imported, and refuse to import a file if it has been or is currently being imported. That's the easy part.

Making circular import chains work means that you need to be able to import a file without knowing the definitions on which it may depend. If those definitions are, for example, macros which change the syntax of the program, then that might be tricky. Otherwise, you can normally collect the transitive closure of all the imports; process the files one at a time to discover the definitions; and then resolve the definitions (and do whatever else needs to be done to compile).

There's a reasonably readable implementation of this strategy in the source code of the Google protobuf compiler (I think you could start browsing [here](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/source/browse/trunk/src/google/protobuf/compiler/importer.h), but it's been a while since I looked at that code.)

Answer (score 1):

There are two quite different situations to be considered. Some of the interesting choices include:

1. The imported file is considered to be simply text that is inserted into the current compilation.

   - The included file can affect compile-time state, so the order of inclusion matters
   - The order of inclusion is unimportant, as long as everything gets defined.
2. The imported file is compiled separately but can 'leak' definitions into the enclosing scope.
3. The imported file has its own module structure/lexical scope so it contributes only exported definitions.

It's trivial to avoid including the same file more than once, but if you have order dependencies you get nasty side effects unless you manage compile time state. The reality is that including raw source code eventually causes more problems than it solves.

My strong preference is to provide only (3). Import should work the same whether the file is raw source, pre-compiled or even written in a different language entirely. It should simple make a set of definitions available for use.

It really isn't a good idea to have entries in a global symbol table the only way to get access to imported functions. Imported files should provide scoping so that you can avoid naming conflicts. The intention is that if A imports B and B imports C then A can call B but not C.

If you're looking for languages on which to model your behaviour, then start by ignoring C/C++ and Javascript (or treat them as examples of what *not* to do). Most modern languages provide a reasonable model, depending on what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Circular dependencies is a problem that still plagues C. It is solved by using the preprocessor to skip the includes if the file has already been loaded. Like this:

```
#ifndef __FOO_H
#define __FOO_H

// other #include's go here

#endif // __FOO_H
```